# How to map the 'Mission Control' key to F3 via Karabiner?

Tags: keyboard, mojave, karabiner

[image]

I am using an external mechanical keyboard. I find that whenever I hit the F3 key, it is mapped to `mission_control`.

Is it possible to remap `mission_control` to something else? In the karabiner Element I cannot find any option of `mission_control`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although the proposed solution works, there are better alternatives IMO. To remap `mission_control` to `right_command` for example, you can also:

- Add a rule to Karabiner-Elements such as:

```json
{
  "type": "basic",
  "from": {
    "key_code": "mission_control",
    "modifiers": {
      "optional": [
        "any"
      ]
    }
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "key_code": "right_command"
    }
  ]
}
```

or

- Go to *System preferences -> Mission Control -> Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts -> Mission Control* and select *Right Command*

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is currently available in the **Function Keys** section of the Karabiner settings! Here you can remap all the keys to anything you want. In my case I just wanted f3 and f4 to be vanilla function keys so I can map them in specific apps/system prefs, and it works!

Perfect way to keep all the other f keys intact while reclaiming 3 and 4 for customization.

[image: screenshot of Function Keys section of Karabiner settings]