# Is it possible to change Fn keys behavior for the non-fn layer?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

I know I can change the function row to work as Fn keys and then use Fn keys as shortcuts. That's not what I want to do. What I want to do is change the default actions of the fn row when not in the Fn mode.

So say F4 alternate is spotlight and F3 alternate is mission control on 2021 MacBook Pros. I wanna customize these to be something else, but I still want to use F4 and F3 like normal in apps for shortcuts, where I need F3 and F4. Is it possible to modify the non-fn layer behavior to do something else?

I tried to press these buttons when selecting keys for shortcuts, but nothing happened, I could only use the Fn layer.

I am willing to use a 3rd party for this, if it's stable.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible at user-level. If you use something like [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) to see how the Mac registers these, you'll see they don't actually arrive in a recognisable form. They're intercepted before the 'face' of the OS gets to see them.

Comment: See answers to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49315/can-i-use-my-f1-f2-etc-keys-as-standard-function-keys-only-for-specific-apps?rq=1 which mentions `Fluor` - might be what you want.